# Conditional fields with more than one selection

Tags: javascript, jquery

I know I'm close on this one. I've been using a Jquery code which shows a field when another form item is selected. I've been able to get the select part working, but I'd like the extra fields to appear when another optioned is selected.

So if I select Table 1, the fields appears. However, if I select Table 2, the field appear for a second and withdraw.

I though just adding a 2nd function would do the trick or adding an 'else' statement between the two. Not sure what to do.

Link to orignal code: http://www.onextrapixel.com/examples/jquery-cookie/

The JS:

```
/*Without jQuery Cookie*/
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#parent1").css("display","none");

$("select").change(function(){
    if ($('select option:selected').val() == "table1" ) {
        $("#parent1").slideDown("fast"); //Slide Down Effect   
    } else {
        $("#parent1").slideUp("fast");  //Slide Up Effect
    }
     }); 
 $("select").change(function(){
    if ($('select option:selected').val() == "table3" ) {
        $("#parent1").slideDown("fast"); //Slide Down Effect   
    } else {
        $("#parent1").slideUp("fast");  //Slide Up Effect
    }
     });                  
});
```

The form:

### Example 1: Display Fields Base On Selected Option WITHOUT jQuery Cookie

If you refresh the page or there is an error message. The last action is not being stored.

::select one::                           
                        Table 1
                        Table 3
                        Table 3

**Parent/Guardian Information:**

Email:

ORG:

Answer (score 0):

Both of your selections are happening at the same time. The if for one, and the else for the other. This cancels everything out (the flash back)

your solution is likely to use "else if" for your second condition. So it should be if, else if, else.